# Buidling an ecommerce frontend for Amazon cloud services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have deployed atmospheric modeling instances in Amazon EC2. I can launch via command line interface, and this sets up a server that I can then query and control via REST-like methods.  It's great for free use but I want to find a way to charge for its use to cover costs plus a little profit.  For the life of me I don't know where to start, and I've searched in all the wrong places.

The scenario I have in mind is to have users register and pay for the time and resources they have used (which could be hours, even days or weeks, plus disc and transfer). I don't want to have to deal with the payments and registrations if I don't have to.

I guess Amazon has some means to facilitate it, but it requires approval and such (not necessarily a bad thing). I have thought of Shopify, but I'm not sure I see a path.  I can do crude stuff with Django, but again I don't really understand the path I would take.  Likewise with Joomla ecommerce.

Is it typical that people would generally roll their own for this kind of thing, or is there an existing framework out there that might help?  Most importantly, are there books or links that help someone at least get a grounding to start on a path?  I find nothing in my long searches.

I suspect this may be off topic, but I don't know where else to ask.  It's all about programming "something" and surely must be relevant to a community out there.